# Linux - Difference between transferring files and creating them - Permissions

Tags: html, linux, apache, permissions, webserver

I am running an Apache web server on a machine running Centos.

**THE PROBLEM:**

When I run the server, everything works fine and I can see the welcome page. The problem occurs when I try to put in an index.html file I previously created into the /var/www/html directory. When I do this I get the error: Forbidden you do not have permission to access index.html on this server. The weird part is I created an index.html file as root in this directory and it works. It was just a simple test html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </head>
</html>
```

This works. So I tried copying the html text from the original index.html to the one I specifically created in the /var/www/html directory and that works. The only problem here is now I have to create lots of new files in the html folder and copy the contents of the old files into the new ones. Also, how would I get images to work? And Hence, my question. So what is the difference between moving files to a directory and creating them there?

*Note*

I know I have set the server up correctly because I am able to access it from another computer so I don't think there is an error with the httpd.conf file. Also, I am not using a .htaccess file. The permissions on each file is the same, only one works and one doesn't. The permissions I have tried are -rwxr--r-- and -rwxrw-rw- and -rwxr-xr-x. I have also changed the owner of the files to be the same. I have tried changing the owner to apache and to root. No luck.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you check selinux status??

Comment: yes, I have tried disabling it as well, I don't think selinux is the issue here because I can connect to the server

Comment: Are you moving files which is created in Windows OS? If yes then try to convert Unix format using dos2unix filename.html filename

Comment: I didn't try it but this sounds like the same kind of thing mentioned below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving files retains the SELinux file context assigned to the file when it was created in its original location. Copying it recreates the file anew in the new location, giving it the appropriate file context for that location.

The appropriate file context can be restored on a directory and all files contained within by running `restorecon` against it. See the `restorecon(8)` man page for details.

Comment: The original files were created on a windows machine and moved to the linux machine

Comment: Does that apply to selinux as well?

Comment: I changed the permissions on the html folder to allow me to drag and drop files from the flash drive and then changed the permissions back.

Comment: The entire flash drive would have been assigned a file context when mounted, so it got that one.

Comment: Man, I love you! That was the problem. You nailed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: for anyone else reading this, I ran resorecon -R on the html folder which reset the selinux configuration on those files.

Comment: Just an after thought, Why would disabling selinux still not have fixed the issue?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't actually disabled. You can use `setenforce(8)` to put SELinux in permissive mode to test (but put it back to enforcing mode after).

Comment: I went to etc/selinux/config and changed SELINUX=enforcing to SELINUX=permissive. Did this not change selinux to permissive mode?